# HQL and subqueries with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I've got the following sql query to retrieve the first row in each group ordered by date:

```
SELECT * FROM pls s1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM pls s2
    ORDER BY s2.date DESC) a 
ON (s1.id = a.id)
GROUP BY s1.name
```

Since joins with subqueries are not valid in HQL, how can it be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make that SQL statement a view?

```
create or replace view v_myview as
SELECT * FROM pls s1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM pls s2
    ORDER BY s2.date DESC) a 
ON (s1.id = a.id)
GROUP BY s1.name
```

Views can be mapped in the same manner as an entity, you just can't insert into them.

Comment: I don't have permissions to create views.

Comment: @CarlosP Thats rough.